# How to extract a one of the values from a string in BIg Query SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I regularly get an update which ends up in a CSV file. In order to use the data from this string (see underneath), I want to extract the first number of the second sentence. The rest of the data is less relevant. I want to do this in Big Query, so I require code that takes the *'250'* from the sentence and saves it in a column. What makes this extra challenging, is the change in values. For instance, one day it could be 4000 and the next only 10.

> "A scheduled daily export of customers - Daily new customers v2 - was
> just made. Download Export These **250** customers have a total value of €
> 4000 and have made 252 orders."

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do this, so I hope you guys can help me with this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract). If it will always be a second number in the text then this could fit:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT("A scheduled daily export of customers - Daily new customers v2 - was just made. Download Export These 250 customers have a total value of € 4000 and have made 252 orders.", r"[0-9]+", 1, 2)
```

[image]